# Which type of motor can I use for my project?

Tags: motors

I am working on a project of linear positioning where a bed is coupled with a motor driven high pitch multi-start back driving lead screw. I need the bed to be freely moving when the motor is not energized.

Currently I am using a NEMA 23 hybrid stepper motor of 1.8 Nm torque with gears since it has significant detent torque. But i need to eliminate the gears.
What kind of motor will be suitable for me?

The approx specs needed are as follows:
Torque: 0.7-1 Nm
max speed: 200 rpm

PS: I read about variable reluctance stepper motors but was unable to find any manufacturers or distributors for it. Can someone please direct me to one, also I am open to consider any other types of electric motors.